# How to use lambda function to insert records into MySQL columns

Tags: java

I am trying to figure out how I can use this lambda function to insert data into my MySQL database. I am using Java and do not have any errors anywhere else in the code.

The reason I have it sorted is because I am putting it into the database in an order. The words with the highest count in the text are at the top of the database list.

```
map.entrySet().stream().sorted((k1, k2) -> -k1.getValue().compareTo(k2.getValue()))             
            .forEach(k -> out.println(k.getKey() + ": " + k.getValue()));
```

I am receiving errors when I try to set

```
pst.setInt(1, k.getValue());
pst.setString(2, k.getKey());
```

Here is the rest of my code

```
public class SomeRandomName {

static Map<String, Integer> count(Scanner scanner) {
    Map<String, Integer> words = new LinkedHashMap<>();
    while (scanner.hasNext()) {
        words.merge(scanner.next(), 1, Integer::sum);
    }
    return words;
}

public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
    
    try (Scanner scanner = new Scanner(new File("FlyingRats.txt")).useDelimiter("\\W+")) {
        Map<String, Integer> map = null;
        try {
            map = count(scanner);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
                
        try(FileWriter fw = new FileWriter("FlyingRats.txt", true);
                BufferedWriter bw = new BufferedWriter(fw);
                PrintWriter out = new PrintWriter(bw)) {
            
            map.entrySet().stream().sorted((k1, k2) -> -k1.getValue().compareTo(k2.getValue()))             
            .forEach(k -> out.println(k.getKey() + ": " + k.getValue()));
                                    
    try {
        Class.forName("com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver");
    } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    String url = "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/eagle_scoutleader";
    String user = "root";
    String password = "**********";
    
    String sql = "INSERT INTO cats(wordCount, wordName) VALUES(?,?)";
    String query = "SELECT * FROM cats";
    
    try (Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection(url, user, password);
            PreparedStatement pst = con.prepareStatement(sql)) {
        
            pst.setInt(1, k.getValue());
            pst.setString(2, k.getKey());
            pst.executeUpdate(); 
        
            Statement statement = con.createStatement();                

            ResultSet rs = statement.executeQuery(query);             

        while (rs.next()) {
           System.out.print(rs.getInt(1));              
           System.out.print(": ");
           System.out.print(rs.getInt(2) + " ");
           System.out.println(rs.getString(3));
       }
                        
    } catch (SQLException ex) {
        
        Logger lgr = Logger.getLogger(SomeRandomName.class.getName());
        lgr.log(Level.SEVERE, ex.getMessage(), ex);       
    }
} }
}}
```

Here is the error I am receiving if I run the code: The errors are on the same line as I state above.

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.Error: Unresolved compilation problems: 
    k cannot be resolved
    k cannot be resolved
at database.DatabaseINSERT.main(DatabaseINSERT.java:85)
```

Comment: "I am receiving errors" -> Please post these errors here, too.

Comment: Hi, I have included the errors.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To be clear: a **lambda expression** is formed like `parameter -> expression` or in case of more parameter they are enclosed in brackets: `(param1, param2) -> expression`.

### Stream and lambda approach

```java
try (Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection(url, user, password);
     PreparedStatement pst = con.prepareStatement(sql)) {

  map.entrySet()
      .stream()
      .sorted((k1, k2) -> -k1.getValue().compareTo(k2.getValue()))
      .forEach(k -> {
        try {
          pst.setInt(1, k.getValue());
          pst.setString(2, k.getKey());
          pst.executeUpdate();
        } catch (SQLException e) {
          throw new RuntimeException(e);
        }
      });
} catch (Exception ex) {
  // handle errors
}
```

You could also skip the `.sorted()` and the `.stream()` steps.

But I don't see any necessity to use lambdas here.

### Loop approach

This would be the more straight-forward thing.

```java
try (Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection(url, user, password);
     PreparedStatement pst = con.prepareStatement(sql)) {
  for (Map.Entry<String, Integer> entry : map.entrySet()) {
    pst.setInt(1, entry.getValue());
    pst.setString(2, entry.getKey());
    pst.executeUpdate();
  }
} catch (Exception ex) {
  // handle errors
}
```

This makes the code a bit cleaner.

Comment: Your first solution solved the issue! Kudos! I attempted the second solution but it does not order the data set with the primary key in the format that is requested by the customer. I plan on getting a book on Java Lambda expressions for Christmas!!!

Comment: Indeed the second version uses a the `map` without any ordering, unlike it is done in the stream approach where the `sorted()` does the trick. You could overcome this with the use of a TreeMap. I think there are quite good tutorials on the web for Lambdas and Streams. Give it a try.

Comment: Btw. I see that you are using a `LinkedHashMap` when reading the values. This map implementation should retain the ordering like "first in first out". But if you want to sort by the key or the value of the map, you could use a `TreeMap` when reading the values to the map.